# Showing that $\sum \sqrt{a_na_{n + 1}}$ converges given that $\sum a_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Suppose a series $\sum a_n$ of nonnegative reals converges; show that $\sum \sqrt{a_na_{n + 1}}$ also converges.

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.SE. We encourage posters to post their ideas on the problem.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan The questions here are very closely related. There's no issue with them both being in the same post.

Comment: I definitely have the intuition as for why this is true but I'm just unsure of how to begin proving it. Looking for some advice regarding that.

Comment: See also: [If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\sum \sqrt{a_na_{n+1}}$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/197400)

Answer (score 3):

Hints: For the first one consider the geometric mean, arithmetic mean inequality.

$$ \sqrt{ab}\leq \frac{a+b}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use the Cauchy criterion and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.$$\left| {\sum\limits_{k = n}^m {{a_k}} } \right| < \varepsilon ,\forall n,m \ge N$$
$$\left| {\sum\limits_{k = n}^m {\sqrt {{a_k}{a_{k + 1}}} } } \right| \le \sqrt {\left| {\sum\limits_{k = n}^m {{a_k}} } \right|\left| {\sum\limits_{k = n}^m {{a_{k + 1}}} } \right|} $$