# If $\sum_n \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}}$ converges, then $\sum_n a_n$ might not converge.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is the other direction of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197400/if-sum-a-n-converges-then-sum-sqrta-na-n1-converges/3772493#3772493) that reads

> Let $a_n>0$ (!) for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$ implies $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}}<\infty$.

I need to prove that "the converse of the last statement is false". I don't want the answer, but to ask if I can use the following argument to prove the statement. To start, I'm confused with the statement "the converse of the last statement is false". Is it enough if I prove, if $\sum_n \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}}$ diverges, then $\sum_n a_n$ must diverge? If this is true, then the proof is easy since I can choose $a_n=1/n$ and prove that $\sum_n a_n$ converges.

Comment: You need to prove that the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{a_na_{n+1}}$ does not necessary imply that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges. So it is enough to find a specific counterexample.

Comment: @Integrand Okay what the hell is your profile bio 

Comment: @Mark yes this would be the standard procedure, but none "easy" counter examples come to my mind.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch He just used ${\sin(x)=x\ \forall\ x \in \mathbb{R}}$, replace as necessary

Comment: @ Integrand and Riemann The worst part is that the conclusion is correct 

Comment: @Integrand your suggestion will not work, notice that $a_n >0$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch hey, he started at point $A$, and made it to point $B$ - both of which are known to be correct, and so the proof is valid. QED

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Addressing the logic of the question rather than the mathematical content:

The original implication is: *Let $a_n>0$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$ implies $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}}<\infty$.* This is an assertion about every sequence in the world, so proving it true requires a general proof that works for all sequences.

The converse of the original implication is: *Let $a_n>0$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}}<\infty$ implies $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$.* If you wanted to prove this true, you would again need an argument that worked for all sequences. But to prove it false, you just need a single counterexample—that is, provide a single sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}}<\infty$ is true but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$ is false.

Answer (score 7):

Let
$$
a_n = \begin{cases}
n^{-1},& n\text{ even}\\
n^{-49},& n \text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks to @user2820579 for correcting an earlier version.